# User profile export to AD issue - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Trying to map user properties to AD Mapped Attributes.
I map the property "SPS-JobTitle" to AD Attribute "title" with direction "export" click add and then ok to save and everything is fine, I then Map "WorkPhone" with Ad Property "telephoneNumber" with direction "Export" and click add then ok  and now property mapping on both "SPS-JobTitle" and "WorkPhone" show two mappings.
If i go into the propertied it will show two mappings under "Property Mapping for Synchronization" both the title and work phone mappings.
If i remove it from one it removes from both.
Clue?

Answer (score 0):

It´s a bug in Sharpoint 2013, confirmed by MS.

I reported it in January but its still not fixed :(

The bug can be reproduced just as you mention by enabling export on several AD properties, the property will get duplicated on the previous propery you enabled export on.

This makes it impossible to use the AD export functionality in Sharepoint 2013 until the bug is fixed.

karl